# How to pass url as parameter to ajax method that is in a service in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am planning to have a separate service for ajax calls. I am trying to call that service from another service, but I want the URL to be passed in via a parameter to the method.

Here is my code:

```
angular.module("Data", []).service("DataService", function ($http) {
    return {
        Data: function (callback) {
            $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php').success(callback);
        }
    }
})

angular.module("Home", ["Data"]).service("HomeService", function (DataService) {
    var customerData = {}
    return {
        Getdata: DataService.getCustomers(function (results) {
            customerData = results;
            console.log(customerData)
        })
    }
})
```

I don't want to hardcode my URL. Instead, I want it to be passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, pass the url to your service method.

```
  angular.module("Data", []).service("DataService", function ($http) {


        return {
            getCustomers: function (url, callback) {
                $http.get(url).success(callback);
            }
        }
    })


angular.module("Home", ["Data"]).service("HomeService", function (DataService) {

        var customerData = {}

        return {
            Getdata: DataService.getCustomers('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php', function (results) {
                customerData = results;
                console.log(customerData)
            })

        }
    })
```